# applying themes to my android app dynamically using spinner selection

Tags: android, themes

In my app 
I am able to change the theme using button clicks(each button for each theme).
When I am trying to change theme by using spinner selection item id, onItemSelectedLisenser() is executing continuously, until the app stops.

I am using a method to change the theme

```
public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
{
    sTheme = theme;
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));

}
```

when i call this method in onItemSelectedListener() it is showing error to change activity to onItemSelectedListener in changeToTheme() method

If i write the same method in another method and call that method in onItemSelectedListener() it is executing continues with out any selection in the spinner.

Please provide any suggestion thanks in advance.